# Autodesk forge oauth2.0 auth code in redirect uri. How to extract that code and use it to exchange for an access token safely?

Tags: reactjs, autodesk-forge

I am using react.

I have a link in my App.js:
`<a href = "url"> Grant Access</a>`

When a user clicks on the link, it brings them to a login page. Once successfully logged in, the user will be redirected to http://localhost:3001/.

However, the authorisation code will be within the url:
'http://localhost:3001/?code=8FNFZAJoEu10gqVxxW_NKw0EDj31XacCApZN1E4z&state='

How would I extract that code and use it for a GET request with axios from my nodejs?

I simply do not know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look at one of our tutorials, for example, https://forge-tutorials.autodesk.io/tutorials/hubs-browser, where we explain the process of extracting the temporary code and exchanging it for an access token. For that particular tutorial, the important line of code is this one: https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-hubs-browser-nodejs/blob/develop/services/forge/auth.js#L12.